# Radio Buttons Revert to Third Choice in PHP Form

Tags: php, forms, radio-button

I have a quiz form that's strictly made with PHP. There are five sets of three radio buttons. (Three for each question in the quiz.) Everything works out fine, but upon clicking the submit button or refreshing the page, the checked radio button always reverts to only option 3 in each set, no matter if the user had originally choose option 1 or 2. How can I make my php so that when the user clicks submit their original choices stay checked?

```
$quiz = array();
$quiz['questions'] = array(
        "Which of these volcanic rocks are capable of floating?", 
        "What gemstone is Arkansas particularly known for?", 
        "What gemstone is assossiated with he month of March?",
        "Which gemstone is an alternative birthstone for June?",
        "In mythology, which of these gemstones are thought to strengthen and clense one's mind?");
$quiz['choices'][0] = array("Basalt", "Obsidian", "Pumice");
$quiz['choices'][1] = array("Diamond", "Amythist", "Arkanite");
$quiz['choices'][2] = array("Emerald", "Aquamarine", "Ruby");
$quiz['choices'][3] = array("Obsidian", "Bloodstone", "Alexandrite");
$quiz['choices'][4] = array("Emerald", "Turquoise", "Amythist");

    //Answers
    $quiz['answers'] = array('Pumice', 'Diamond', 'Aquamarine', 'Alexandrite', 'Emerald', 'submit');

foreach ($quiz['questions'] as $key => $question){
       echo "<h3>" . $question . "</h3>";

foreach($quiz['choices'][$key] as $choice){

    echo "<label>";

    if(isset($_POST[$key])){
        echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"$key\" value=\"$choice\" id=\"$choice\" checked> " . $choice . "<br>";

    }else{
        echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"$key\" value=\"$choice\" id=\"$choice\"> " . $choice . "<br>";
    }

    echo "</label>";

}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It works for me

```
<?php
$quiz = array();
$quiz['questions'] = array(
    "Which of these volcanic rocks are capable of floating?",
    "What gemstone is Arkansas particularly known for?",
    "What gemstone is assossiated with he month of March?",
    "Which gemstone is an alternative birthstone for June?",
    "In mythology, which of these gemstones are thought to strengthen and clense one's mind?");
$quiz['choices'][0] = array("Basalt", "Obsidian", "Pumice");
$quiz['choices'][1] = array("Diamond", "Amythist", "Arkanite");
$quiz['choices'][2] = array("Emerald", "Aquamarine", "Ruby");
$quiz['choices'][3] = array("Obsidian", "Bloodstone", "Alexandrite");
$quiz['choices'][4] = array("Emerald", "Turquoise", "Amythist");

//Answers
$quiz['answers'] = array('Pumice', 'Diamond', 'Aquamarine', 'Alexandrite', 'Emerald', 'submit');

foreach ($quiz['questions'] as $key => $question) {
    echo "<h3>" . $question . "</h3>";

    foreach ($quiz['choices'][$key] as $choice) {

        echo "<label>";

        if (isset($_POST[$key]) && $_POST[$key] == $choice) {
            echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"$key\" value=\"$choice\" id=\"$choice\" checked> " . $choice . "<br>";

        } else {
            echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"$key\" value=\"$choice\" id=\"$choice\"> " . $choice . "<br>";
        }

        echo "</label>";

    }
}
```

**EDIT**

You can change the last `foreach` for the follow code. It looks cleaner.

```
foreach ($quiz['questions'] as $key => $question) {
    echo "<h3>" . $question . "</h3>";
    foreach ($quiz['choices'][$key] as $choice) {
        echo "<label>";
        $checked = isset($_POST[$key]) && $_POST[$key] == $choice ? "checked" : "";
        echo '<input type="radio" name="' . $key . '" value="' . $choice . '" id="' . $choice . '" ' . $checked . '>' . $choice . '<br>';
        echo "</label>";

    }
}
```

Comment: I can't use this in my document because it's a php html mix. My code up there was extracted from solid php.

Comment: Nope. The radio buttons are eliminated entirely. Questions stay, though.

Comment: Can you please `print_r($quiz);` before the first `foreach`, So I can see how the array looks like

Comment: got it. You were only checking if `POST[$key]`  were set. You need to compare if `POST[$key]` is equals `$choice`

Comment: Is there something that you changed outside of the foreach loops? Because now I get no checked radios.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72386/discussion-between-lea-tano-and-sarah-day).

Comment: I only change  `if(isset($_POST[$key]))` to `if(isset($_POST[$key]) && $_POST[$key] == $choice)` I just opened a chat room, in order to avoiding extended discussions. Please enter to the chat room

Comment: @SarahDay does it fix your issue?